# Python: Sending POST request doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a webpage sending POST to fill a form, generally I use selenium to scrape a page with python, but I recently read that sending a POST request is a better way to scrape results. Anyway, I followed some instructions for make my code, but when I post my data, I get the same page with the form filled (the POST doesn't submit the form), what I'm doing wrong? Also the same page has another form to fill after the first, so if I achieve fill the first form I really don't know how to keep that response for get the final response, so if someone can help with some ideas, I reall would appreciate it! Thanks and I include my code and the page that I'm looking for scrape final quotation:

https://www.santander.cl/cotizador-web/

```
import requests, lxml.html
import time

s = requests.session()
login = s.get('https://www.santander.cl/cotizador-web/cotizador/pasosSolicitud.xhtml')
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}

form['pasosForm:marcas']='27'
form['pasosForm:modelos']='1978'
form['pasosForm:ano']='2015'
form['pasosForm:uso']='1'
form['pasosForm:j_id93373712_1a32e354_input']='on'
form['formDialogCotiSelec:j_id216370348_64c01a10_active'] = '1'
form['javax.faces.partial.execute']='pasosForm pasosForm:siguiente1'

response = s.post('https://www.santander.cl/cotizador-web/cotizador/pasosSolicitud.xhtml', data=form)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that all forms have hidden field like this

```
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" 
id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="zDmSF7aJ4QSdyqjY5D4dGbfEaQr5OiS6WorNARY6pfHWSXIe/APb5e
/wcHsiGvPVaXW4IFpVHFyFHNSSJMPdHt2mhaYm4TQ9WPo+TQgWFTB1ZRE1wwiJtXQfmKuwE2+R+iRmONBAmZCR9E8x" />
```

It's csrf token and generated from current session. You should visit(create session) of form page, before you make post request.

More info here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks! I correct that part and my program fill the form (the values are marked like "selected in the HTML code), but still doesn't get the next page of the form, is like the program is not submitting the form... you have some idea? Thanks!